# Why .equals(null) doesn't work and == null works?

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, return, equals

I am implementing binary tree and I came across the code like this

```
if(head.equals(null)) return;
```

It gives me null pointer error whereas if I do it the other way

```
if(head == null) return;
```

It works just fine.
Please tell me why this happens?
I am really sorry if anyone has already asked it. I searched but not found any question matching this description.

Comment: If you can call equals method, then you object is not null.

Comment: Please, put some efforts in trying to understand the underlying structures and mechanisms. If head is null, you get a NullPointerException by calling any of its methods...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because `equals` is a method, so it requires an object to be called on.  If `head` is `null`, then there is no object.

Comment: Also worth noting that the contract for Object.equals specifically states that o.equals(null) should be false: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I called it on object itself.
    rightNode.equals(null)

Comment: @ADi Nope. `rightNode` is *not an object*, it's a variable. If that variable happens to currently point at an existent object, then you can call the object's `equals` method. Otherwise, (if the variable's value is null, meaning it points at no object) then there's no object to call the method on. Don't worry, you will get it :)